# Understanding the Impact of a MIPS Program on a Direct Mapped Data Cache

Tags: caching, mips, execution, processor

I am trying to understand the behavior of a direct mapped data cache in a MIPS processor. I have been given a program and asked to determine which sets of the cache have been updated after the program has been executed. I am having trouble determining the set number, valid bit, and tag value of the data cache.

Here is the program in question:

`1 lui $t0,0x12ff`

`2 lw $t1,0x1240($t0)`

`3 lw $t2,0x5aa4($t0)`

`4 lw $t3,0x4248($t0)`

Can someone help me understand how to approach this problem and what the solution would look like?

Thank you in advance!

I tried solving the problem by first understanding the memory addresses being loaded in the program. I calculated the memory address for each of the load instructions by adding the base address stored in $t0 and the offset. Then I tried to determine the set number by dividing the memory address by the block size of 32 bytes. I expected to get an integer value as the result, but instead, I got a decimal value. I wasn't sure how to proceed after that. I tried looking at the binary representation of the memory address and the block size to see if I could find a pattern, but I was unable to do so. I was stuck at this point and couldn't figure out how to determine the set number.

Comment: When the access is within a block but not at the beginning of that block, you'll have a fractional/decimal value instead of an integer.  Just ignore the decimal part.  For example, let's say with a block size of 32, we access the byte at address 35.  35/32 = 1.09375.  The 1 is the set number and the decimal part, 0.9375, is the block offset, divided by 32, so multiplying back, we have 0.9375*32= 3 block offset of 3.

Comment: Now, you have to eliminate the tag bits or this won't work in general, but in my example of address 35, we are so close to address 0 that the tag bits are all zeros.

Comment: So, the first thing to do is subdivide the address into its three subcomponent fields: tag bits, index bits, and block offset bits.  Those three fields will each have a bit count, and when you want to know the index (block number, I think you're calling it a set #) you write the address in binary and take the index bits, alone, and right justify them and then interpret that as an unsigned number.